# How to use gcc -7 if a have build essential installed (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: compiling, gcc, versions, g++

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and installed build-essential because I need gfortran, gcc, g++. I'm trying to run Nek5000 but I get an error with `makenek`:

`gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-plt’`

I read that the gcc version is causing it, so I installed gcc-7 and re-run, but it seems that the program is still compiling with the gcc from build-essential (5.4.0) because I keep getting the same error output.

Do you know if I can "select" to compile with gcc-7? Or is it better to uninstall build essential and install gcc, g++, etc. apart? Also, if you have another idea in order to solve the mentioned error I would appreciate your thoughts a lot.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Does the `makenek` script respect common build environment variables? for example, did you try `CC=gcc-7 makenek`? If not, you could probably edit makenek to set the desired value of `CC`. As a last resort, you can always re-link `/usr/bin/gcc` to `gcc-7` either manually or via update-alternatives.

Comment: Hi! I tried it but now i have the error:

`fatal error: mpi.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio`
` #include <mpi.h>`
`          ^~~~~~~`

Comment: You will need to make sure you install all the build dependencies - there are 2 common MPI implementations, I *think* the one you want is MPICH (`libmpich-dev`) but check with the software's documentation