# Failing with Nek5000

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to build an example on Nek5000 with the included makenek script using mpi (installed mpich), but I get an error. Consulting the indicated file (build.log) this error is showed:

```
mpicc -O2 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/hp/anaconda3/include -I./src  -DMPI -DUNDERSCORE -DGLOBAL_LONG_LONG -DPREFIX=gslib_ -DFPREFIX=fgslib_ -c src/sort.c -o src/sort.o'
mpicc -O2 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/hp/anaconda3/include -I./src  -DMPI -DUNDERSCORE -DGLOBAL_LONG_LONG -DPREFIX=gslib_ -DFPREFIX=fgslib_ -c src/sarray_transfer.c -o src/sarray_transfer.o
mpicc -O2 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/hp/anaconda3/include -I./src  -DMPI -DUNDERSCORE -DGLOBAL_LONG_LONG -DPREFIX=gslib_ -DFPREFIX=fgslib_ -c src/sarray_sort.c -o src/sarray_sort.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-plt’
Makefile:130: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'src/sort.o'
make: *** [src/sort.o] Error 1
make: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-plt’
Makefile:130: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'src/gs.o'
make: *** [src/gs.o] Error 1
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-plt’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-plt’
Makefile:130: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'src/sarray_sort.o'
make: *** [src/sarray_sort.o] Error 1
Makefile:130: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'src/sarray_transfer.o'
make: *** [src/sarray_transfer.o] Error 1
```

I'm new to Linux, so I don't really know if this has something to do with anaconda, if it is a compiler issue or another thing. Would appreciate a lot your thoughts and help. If you need more information please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: This is likely related to your [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321759/how-to-use-gcc-7-if-a-have-build-essential-installed-ubuntu-16-04) - in particular, you need to make sure that `mpicc` is using a suitably recent version of `gcc` (perhaps by exporting `MPICH_CC=gcc-7` into your build environment).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! I will try those solutions.